# Comparing 2 json in cypress (for loop problem)

Tags: json, for-loop, comparison, cypress

I'm writing cypress tests and have to compare 2 json files, comparing element by element.
I know that cypress and for loops are not working together, so if my code is like this, I will get nothing:

```
cy.fixture('refEquityTable').then(function(refEquityTable) { 
                cy.fixture('equityTable').then(equityTable => {  
                    for (let i = 1; i < refEquityTable.data[0].length; i++) {
                        for (let j = 1; j < Object.keys(refEquityTable).length; j++) {
                    expect(equityTable.data[0][0]).to.equal(refEquityTable.data[0][0]);
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
```

And if I remove for and put concrete indexes in [] I will get what I need.

```
cy.fixture('refEquityTable').then(function(refEquityTable) { 
                cy.fixture('equityTable').then(equityTable => {  
                    expect(equityTable.data[0][5]).to.equal(refEquityTable.data[0][5]);
                     
                })
            })
```

How to go through all the elements in json? All the elements are arrays with the same length.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have handled the asynchronous parts correctly with `cy.fixture(...).then(...)` so for loops are ok to use once both files have been read.

It's just this `expect(equityTable.data[0][0]).to.equal(refEquityTable.data[0][0])` is using `[0][0]` on every iteration - it should probably be `[i]` and `[j]` at the ending index.

```js
cy.fixture('refEquityTable').then(function(refEquityTable) { 
  cy.fixture('equityTable').then(equityTable => {  
    for (let i = 1; i < refEquityTable.data[0].length; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j < Object.keys(refEquityTable).length; j++) {
        expect(equityTable.data[0][i]).to.equal(refEquityTable.data[0][j]);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

or just a single index if the arrays match exactly

```js
cy.fixture('refEquityTable').then(function(refEquityTable) { 
  cy.fixture('equityTable').then(equityTable => {  
    for (let i = 1; i < refEquityTable.data[0].length; i++) {
      expect(equityTable.data[0][i]).to.equal(refEquityTable.data[0][i]);
    }
  })
})
```

You could also look for a ChaiJs expression, maybe as simple as

```js
cy.fixture('refEquityTable').then(function(refEquityTable) { 
  cy.fixture('equityTable').then(equityTable => {  
    expect(refEquityTable).to.deep.eq(equityTable)
  })
})
```